# confirmation dialog in html with if statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like to make a confirmation message presented whenever the user want to delete

**option 1** :If  yes  then  delete  student  from  database  and  the  user  should  be  redirected  to
index.php 

**option 2:** If no, the the user should be redirected to show.php
I have tried, but I could not satisfy option 2 what so ever 
this is my code :

```
<body>
<center><h1>Delete record</h1></center>
<center><form action="del.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">
Enter the ID for student you want to delete :
</br><input type="text" name="id"/>        </br>
</br>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Delete" style="width: 219px"/> </br>
<a href = "change.html">Back</a>


</form></center>
</body>
```

**Update** :

I have found a solution . For anyone who seeks it . Thanks for your time

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

```
function delfunction(form) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?")) {
            form.submit();
        }

        else {
           window.location = 'show.php';
        }
    }
   </script>
<title>Delete</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1>Delete</h1></center>


<center><form action="del.php" method ="post" >

Enter the ID for student you want to delete :<br />
    <input type="text" name="id"/><br />
    </br>


<input type="button" onclick="delfunction(this.form);" value="Delete !" style="width: 115px"/><br />
    <a href = "change.html">Back</a>


</form></center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you closed your form right after the action attr. why?

Comment: @Rizier123 no I have closed it at the end

Comment: `onsubmit="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return true;} else {return false; window.location = 'show.php'}"`?

Comment: @Rizier123 it performs the action on true, but in clicking cancel it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function areyousure(id)
{
    jConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", "Delete Message", function (callback) {
        if (callback) {
           window.location='delete_student.php?id='+id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>

<form onclick="return areyousure('2');">
```

Comment: Thanks . It does not view any dialog . Something wrong

Comment: try this..`<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">Delete</a>`